How can i use the spotbugs eclipse plugin from local spotbugs build?
I wrote a new detector for spotbugs, and part of it requires the project files to be on classpath to work, so I'm trying to build and use the spotbugs eclipse plugin locally. How can i do that?

You can put the Eclipse plugin into the dropins folder and restart Eclipse. It is unclear to me what you asking. Which project files? Which classpath? What did you build? Did you fork, edit and build the spotbugs project?

I forked edited and built the spotbugs project. I wrote a detector that detects when certain exceptions which would cause information leaks if they reached the user are rethrown. For this the program traverses the exception hierarchy to find out if it's an instance of a subclass of Exception. If the exception being analyzed is a custom exception, the project needs to be on the spotbugs auxclasspath for this to work if I understood things right. I think if I use it as a plugin that will work. So if I copy the eclipse plugin project into the dropins folder it will register it as a plugin?

Yes, the build via Gradle is unusual for an Eclipse plugin, but this should not be a problem. You can verify that the plugin is active in Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details in the tab Plug-ins (the last part of the version should contain the date in the format yyyyMMddHHmm).
